What is the reward for dodging Spades with 60 HP remaining?
In the Deltarune mod RIBBIT by TheMaxine, there is a section early on when you first enter the dark world where you dodge a barrage of white spades. At the end, there's a message saying you get a reward if you survive with at least 60 HP.
What is the reward for surviving the spades with at least 60 HP?

Screenshot from I played the BEST Deltarune Mod (36:16) by Shayy

A quick search on Youtube brought me to a charity stream. There you can easily see the reward right at the start.
You get a Defibrillator that revives fallen allies and your defense permanently goes up by 1.


